# Window.click event does not fire on IOS safari - JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, html, ios, angularjs, safari

**Vanilla javascript -**

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert('click fired');});
```

**with angular 2 + -**

```
 @HostListener('window: click', ['$event'])
        public iosSafariClick(e: any): void {
         alert('event fired');
        }
```

None of this method worked on IOS safari on iPad.

Unless I click some button, hyperlink, or any actionable item, ***Click*** event is not fired.

My goal is to fire ***blur*** event on a 'div element'.

To do so I am trying to check if the any click event fired on HTML body and check if it was on not the 'div element'.

**HTML >**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id= 'menu'>123...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Angular Component > typescript >**

```
 @HostListener('window: click', ['$event'])
   public iosSafariClick(e: any): void {
     if(e.target.id !== 'menu'){
       this.menu = false;  // to close menu 
     }        
   }
```

Is there any way using javascript or angular to overcome this hurdle?

Comment: Does someone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using touch based devices, the events issued to the browsers are different.
It also gives the developer accurate use cases, to design and develop around.

I would assume that since there is no *mouse* then there will be no click event.

Taken from MDN:
In order to provide quality support for touch-based user interfaces, touch events offer the ability to interpret finger (or stylus) activity on touch screens or trackpads.

Try using:
`document.addEventListener('touchstart', () => console.log('touch called'));`

You can always opt to using `function () {}` instead of `() => {}`

See full details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: Tried TouchEnd didn't work. But TouchStart works just fine. Thanks mate !

Answer (score 5):

I've forgotten more about Angular than I remember but I ran into this same problem when click was mapped to 'window.' Switch the listener from 'window' to 'body' fixed the issue in Safari.

Good listener

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('clicked ', e)
// oh yeah, I'm good!
})
```

Bad listener

```
window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('clicked ', e)
// oh yeah, I'm good!
})
```